# How to use 3D models in a IOS app?

Tags: ios, 3d

I have some models from Solidworks. I exported IGS file and then .OBJ file. I used NinevehGL to use it but it couldn't read the file. I guess it is because the file is 10MB.

Is there any other way to load files into IOS applications?

Comment: NinevehGL itself is a good choice...

Comment: If NinevehGL can't open it, then it might have serious problems.  Can you open it with another application?

Comment: I can see the vertices inside it. I dont have any other application that will load obj file.

Comment: @Burak Can Blender open the file on desktop?

Comment: No, I don't see anything.